# How to interchange execution of statement manually in stored procedure of SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have more than 8 update statements in a stored procedure. The requirement may come that their may be different scenario that once i want to execute 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8th statement and second time 3,8,5,4,1,2,7,6th statement and like  this......i can use if condition and but in every if condition i have to use more than 8 update statement and i have to shuffle update statement each and every condition. it is very long procedure......so can we use while something while loop over here?....so on ...like this. How to achieve this in SQL Server?

example :-
create proc sp_a @condition
as begin
if @conditon='abc'
update statement 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
if @condition ='xyz'
update statement 5,4,3,7,2,1,8,6
if @condition ='pqr'
update statement 8,3,7,5,4,2,6,1
.
.
.
.
.
.
.so on.....
end

Comment: put all condition in if else clause

Comment: I cannot follow what you want to do without an example.  Why would the ordering matter?

Comment: You could pass in a list using a table-value parameter (TVP), specifying the in order which to execute the statements. Use a cursor to run through the list and execute the appropriate statement on each pass. This wouldn't happen to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: the example you give preserves the order but just skips some. Do you mean interchange or skip?

Comment: their may be different scenario that once i want to execute 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8th statement and second time 3,8,5,4,1,2,7,6th statement and so on......i can mention if condition and i can do shuffle but in similar 20 statement many times it is very long ......so can we use while something while loop over here?

Comment: And sometimes 6, 6, 6? Or must the statements be unique in any given scenario? It appears that you don't want to pass in an actual order, i. e. "5, 4, 9", but a code that is used to look up an order, i.e. "Frabjous Day" is internally translated into "42". Is that correct?

Comment: each time every statement single time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion.  Suppose your update procedure is called 'ProcUpdate'.  Modify it as follows:

- Add a parameter, @RunStep INT, to the procedure.
- Before the first update statement, add "IF @RunStep = 1 BEGIN"
- Between the first and second update statements add "END ELSE IF @RunStep = 2 BEGIN"
- ...etc...
- After the last update statement add "END"

ProcUpdate ends out looking something like this...

```
create procedure ProcUpdate @RunStep int, ... other params ...
as begin
    if @RunStep = 1 begin
        ... first update here ...
    end
    else if @RunStep = 2 begin
        ... second update here ...
    end
    ... repeat the pattern as needed
end;
```

Next, create a wrapper stored procedure, let's call it "WrapperUpdate".  It looks like this...

```
create procedure dbo.WrapperUpdate @Condition NVARCHAR(20)
as begin
    if @Condition = 'abc' begin
        execute ProcUpdate 1;
        execute ProcUpdate 2;
        execute ProcUpdate 5;
        ... whatever sequence is called for ...
    end
    else if @Condition = 'def' begin
        execute ProcUpdate 2;
        execute ProcUpdate 5;
        execute ProcUpdate 3;
        ... whatever sequence is called for ...
    end
    ... repeat the pattern as necessary ...
end;
```

It gets a bit more complicated if the different updates need different parameters, but the idea is the same.